# Bootstrap 3/FlatUI - Centered logo -> nav links stacked?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a small logo to the navbar and centered it responsively.

My problem is that since then, the right nav links ( three of them ) all collapse to be stacked, although there is enough space.

What property need I adapt to achieve my desired effect ?

[image: Picture]

## Relevant HTML

```
<header class="header-11">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="navbar col-sm-12" role="navigation">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"></button>
                                <a class="brand" href="#"><!-- <img src="img/logo@2x.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">  -->GRATIS-VERSAND <br> <div id="pete">INNERHALB DEUTSCHLANDS</div></a>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/nicetights.PNG" class="ri"></div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
                                <ul class="nav pull-left">
                                    <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li> -->
                                    <li><a href="#">KAUFEN </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">&Uuml;BER </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">WARENKORB</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">SIGN IN</a>
                                </form> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
```

## Relevant CSS

```
img.ri
{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: inline-block;
  /*box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);*/
}

img.ri:empty
{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  img.ri {
      max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  img.ri {
      max-height: 90%;
  }
}
.logoss {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .logoss {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
.logoss > .container {
  display: table;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
.logoss > .container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .logoss {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

### FIDDLE - Kind of solved the problem myself

http://jsfiddle.net/BMS4n/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get the HTML + CSS to render since the images don't load. Try `display: inline-block`

**[More information](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)**

Comment: It is already in the mentioned code. I think i might provide a fiddle of this in a minute.

Comment: Here is the fiddle:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/BMS4n/)

It seems I solved the problem: 
position: absolute;
  max-width: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 0px;